24.10 stream to chromecast / dlna
So I'd like to stream audio from my desktop to my chromecast-audio devices. This is working if there is some chromecast button in an application. But not all applications have it.
Some googling made me believe that pa-dlna should make that easy for me. But not sure how this would work.
In installed it, but cannot select a chromecast as an output device. Isn't that how it should it work?
I am on ubuntu 22.10
